# PHP If then and switch statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

OK, first, this is very special problem. I was working on PHP for long time, and I don't know why this happened.

I have a function adminUpdate. This function will return true. I set it always return true for testing.

Then I have function take that result.

```
static function result2JSON($result,$options = array()) {

        if($result == "permission") {
            echo "permission";
        }

        if($result == true) {
            echo "true";
        }


        switch ($result) {
            case 'permission':
                die($result."xxx permission");
                $json = self::setJSON("Permission");
                break;
            case 'exist':
                $json = self::setJSON("Exist");
                break;
            case false:
                $json = self::setJSON("Error");
                break;
            case "":
                $json = self::setJSON("Error");
                break;
            case 1 :
                $json = self::setJSON("OK");
                break;
            case true:
                $json = self::setJSON("OK");
                break;
            default:
                $json = self::setJSON("OK");
                break;
        }


        $json = array_merge($json,$options);


        return $json;

    }
```

These "Echo" use for testing on this case.
So, $result always = true before taken by this function.

But this is output I got:

```
permissiontrueResult = 1 IN permission section
```

That mean the $result = Permission , and then == true, and then == "permission" on switch.
Why is that ?

Comment: use `===` to compare value, or `else if`

Comment: thanks guys, now I learn , this case can't use switch because it mix both true | false | string. This case must be if | else if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use identity check === rather than a check for equality.

In php, a non empty string is interpreted as true.

```
$result = "permission";
if($result)
     echo 'String interpreted as true';
```

Take a Look at Boolean page on php.net (Short) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php
and the PHP Comparison Operators page...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Strings with stuff in them evaluate to true if you try and treat them as a boolean. (well, okay, the string "0" evaluates to False. php is weird.)

So, if you want to see if a variable is actually true, you have to use a comparison that also checks type:

```
if ($result === "permission") { ... }

if ($result === True) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace every occurrence of `==` with `===`

Comment: @njk reading my answer should provide enough information for an intelligent reader to go and read more about it in the manual (or alternatively, they can ask). -1 should be clicked when an answer is not useful. Now, is it ?

Comment: Down voting is subjective. I feel your answer is too simple and does not provide a 'why', just 'what'. Perhaps guiding the OP to the the comparison operators?

Comment: I take your saying that my answer is simple as a compliment! Anything you do or think should be considered subjective :) , but, assuming you'll act according to the guidelines of SO, up/down-vote should be done according to the *usefulness* of an answer. Place your cursor on the down-vote arrow to see the definition.

Comment: A useful answer is one that explains why the change needs to happen.

Comment: I disagree :) a useful answer is one that will give you "a push" in the right direction and will encourage you to dig in further and learn by yourself. Not an answer that will "spoon-feed" you.

Comment: I would remove my down vote if you expanded on your answer. Again, we have different approaches to helping others, and yours just doesn't contain explanations.